# Explain why every proper subgroup must be cyclic.

Tags: group-theory

Let G be the group with presentation $< x, y : x^4=1; x^2=y^2; xy=yx^{-1} >$.

1. Find the order of each of the eight elements.
2. How many elements of order 2 are there?
3. Explain why every proper subgroup must be cyclic.

We first find the number of elements in G. The group will necessarily contain the powers of x, these begin $1,x,x^2,x^3$ as well as their products by y: $y,yx,yx^2,yx^3$. Other products, such as xy, will also need to be in G, but the relation $xy=yx^{-1}$ ensures this In fact, consider the following list of 8 elements: $$1,x,x^2,x^3,y,yx,yx^2,yx^3$$ These clearly must be in G. We have the following table:

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
$\cdot$ & 1 & $y$ & $y^2$ & $y^3$ & $x$ & $xy$ & $xy^2$ & $xy^3$ \\ \hline
1 & 1 & $y$ & $y^2$ & $y^3$ & $x$ & $xy$ & $xy^2$ & $xy^3$ \\ \hline
$y$ & $y$ & $y^2$ & $y^3$ & 1 & $xy^3$ & $x$ & $xy$ & $xy^2$ \\ \hline
$y^2$ & $y^2$ & $y^3$ & 1 & $y$ & $xy^2$ & $xy^3$ & $x$ & $xy$ \\ \hline
$y^3$ & $y^3$ & 1 & $y$ & $y^2$ & $xy$ & $xy^2$ & $xy^3$ & $x$ \\ \hline
$x$ & $x$ & $xy$ & $xy^2$ & $xy^3$ & $y^2$ & $y^3$ & 1 & $y$ \\ \hline
$xy$ & $xy$ & $xy^2$ & $xy^3$ & $x$ & $y$ & $y^2$ & $y^3$ & 1 \\ \hline
$xy^2$ & $xy^2$ & $xy^3$ & $x$ & $xy$ & 1 & $y$ & $y^2$ & $y^3$ \\ \hline
$xy^3$ & $xy^3$ & $x$ & $xy$ & $xy^2$ & $y^3$ & 1 & $y$ & $y^2$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

**Find the order of each of the eight elements.**

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
< 1 > = 1 & \\
< y > = 4 & \,because y^4=y^2y^2=x^2x^2=x^4=1 \\
< y^2 > = 2 & \,because (y^2)^2=(x^2)^2=x^4=1 \\
< y^3 > = 4 & \,because (y^3)^4=(y^4)^3=(y^2y^2)^3=(x^2x^2)^3=(x^4)^3=1^3=1 \\
< x > = 4 & \,because x^4=1 \\
< xy > = 2 &  \,because (xy)^2=x^2y^2=x^2x^2=x^4=1 \\
< xy^2 > = 4 & \,because (xy^2)^4=(xx^2)^4=(x^3)^4=(x^4)^3=1^3=1\\
< xy^3 > =4 & \,because (xy^3)^4=x^4(y^3)^4=1(y^4)^3=(y^2y^2)^3=(x^2x^2)^3=(x^4)^3=1^3\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

**How many elements of order 2 are there?**

There are only two elements with order 2, which are $y^2$ and $xy$, as seen above.

**Explain why every proper subgroup must be cyclic.**

I am not sure how to explain this. I know that the group itself is cyclic because this group is isomorphic to $C_2 x C_2 x C_2 x C_2$.

Comment: You have made a mistake. $xy$ has order $4$, not $2$. Note that $(xy)^2 \ne x^2y^2$. In fact $y^2$ is the only element of order $2$. Hence $G$ has no subgroups isomorphic to $C_2 \times C_2$, so all proper subgroups must be cyclic.

Comment: @DerekHolt Why is it that $(xy)^2 \neq x^2y^2$?